# Is a Yogacara any form of solipsism?

Tags: buddhism

Is yogacara some form of solipsism? every Buddhist who believes in Yogacara should believe that only he has consciousness, while other people and living beings around him do not have consciousness and that they are just philosophical zombies that exist only in his imagination?

Comment: Who is nevo? We discussed a similar question here https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78685/different-between-buddhism-and-solipsism/78696#78696 Yogachara is called the 'mind only' school. It is not monistic, as can be understood from the metaphor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net

Comment: Someone *really* wants to equate Buddhism with solipsism, for reasons unknown. I mean, how many variations of this question have popped up from ostensibly new users..? vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

No. Yogacara school cannot be a form of solipsism because they are the development of Madhyamika school. As such, they believe in [the ultimate reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_truths_doctrine). For Yogacarins, the conventional reality is Mind-Only.

The important piece is that our mind is in contact with the ultimate reality through storehouse consciousness (ālāyavijñāna), but it is "tainted" by the Self-grasping (manas) [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses). It means that we never perceive things in themselves, but merely mind representations of them. Those representations and their nature always grow from karmic seeds.

In practice, this is very close to Kantianism.

If you want to read a thorough account of Yogacara and their multi-leveled concept of mind, read *Transformation at the Base: Fifty Verses on the Nature of Consciousness* by Thich Nhat Han.

Comment: "It means that we never perceive things in themselves, but merely mind representations of them" In Kantianism there is still a notion that the "thing in itself" exists independently of the mind even if we can never get beyond our own representations. I would think this would be a point on which Mahayana doctrines like Yogacara would disagree, since it seems to go against the teachings on [emptiness/interdependence](https://www.lionsroar.com/it-starts-from-zero-may-2013/) (Thich Nhat Hanh uses the term "interbeing", see [here](https://www.mindfulnessbell.org/archive/tag/parakalpita) for ex.)

Comment: @Hypnosifl Well, yes. Two truths are ultimately one in Yogacara. Kant didn't explicitly take the same leap as Schopenhauer did, who took Kant to his conclusive and proclaimed monism. And so Yogacara is typically associated with Schopenhauer in terms of influence. But Kant wasn't a dualist either; he was agnostic about it. There are many implications and implicit readings of Kant since we know that a phenomenon is merely a manifestation of noumenon - its object of interest. Not a separate substance. Also, see note on Saam Trivedi's interpretation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogachara#Idealism

Answer (score 0):

> the collectivity of consciousness, yields the metaphysical explication
> of mutual interdependence and the prescription of norms for
> compassionate actions.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11712-019-09674-3

Yogacarins have been, historically, warned of their arrogance, however

> Running through all of these controversies is an undercurrent of
> resentment at the Yogācāras' “undigested pride” in their
> interpretation of the central texts of the Mahāyāna. Bhāviveka
> provides the most extensive available evidence about the intellectual
> and emotional shape of this controversy in what might be called the
> classic period of Indian Yogācāra (the period of Dharmapāla,
> Sthiramati, and Xuanzang). Like the sixth-century proponents of the
> Yogācāra, one ignores Bhāviveka at one’s peril.

https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780190231286.001.0001/acprof-9780190231286-chapter-6

Comment: that is, a Buddhist who believes in yogachara, believes that other people exist independently of his imagination and that all people have individual streams of mind?

Comment: inter-dependently, but that doesn't prohibit different  "streams" and causal "series"

Comment: i don't know the precise definition of "individual" in philosophy, sorry

Comment: I mean, how can other minds exist in Yogachara if all reality arises in my imagination?

Comment: it's not just "your" imagination. there are **layers** to a lot of buddhist thinking. read the link first! @Jerry

Comment: @Jerry: Basically, deconstruct the conventional self, and intuitions derived from our cognitive biases first, and you can't build a hard line between self & world - so it applies both ways, world as mind, but mind as causally conditioned. Intersubjectivity.